# Is there a map of spectra implementing the inverse of the Thom isomorphism?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

In the top answer to the question ["Is there a map of spectra implementing the Thom isomorphism?"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46787/is-there-a-map-of-spectra-implementing-the-thom-isomorphism) it is explained (with a reference to Rudyaks book) that from a rank $r$ vector bundle $\mu:V\to X$, a spectrum $E$ with multiplication $m:E\wedge E\to E$ and a Thom class $t:X^\mu\to \Sigma^r E$ one gets the Thom isomorphism:

The (cohomological) Thom isomorphism sends a map $x:X_+\to E^n$ of spectra to the composition
$$
X^\mu\to X_+\wedge X^\mu\xrightarrow{x\wedge t}E^n\wedge E^r\xrightarrow{m}E^{n+r}.
$$
The induced isomorphism on homotopy groups is then $E^{n}(X_+)\cong E^{n+r}(X^\mu)$.

> Is it possible to give an inverse map, i.e. a map sending a $X^\mu\to E^{n+r}$ to an $X_+\to E^n$ on the level of spectra, too?

I am not asking for a proof of the Thom isomorphism. Even with the existence of such a map one has to prove that the correspondence induces an isomorphism on homotopy groups.

Answer (score 5):

You find the inverse Thom isomorphism if you generalize the construction from my answer to the [old question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46787/is-there-a-map-of-spectra-implementing-the-thom-isomorphism/46809#46809) to stable vector bundles. The point is that if you have two stable vector bundles $\eta$ and $\mu$ over $X$, then you get a diagonal map

$$X^{\eta\oplus\mu} \to X^{\eta} \wedge X^{\mu}.$$

Now if there is a Thom class $X^{\mu} \to \Sigma^n E$, then there is a Thom class $X^{-\mu} \to \Sigma^{-n} E$; and the inverse to the Thom isomorphism maps an element $X^{\mu}\to \Sigma^k E$ to the composition

$$X \to X^{\mu} \wedge X^{-\mu} \to \Sigma^k E \wedge \Sigma^{-n} E \to \Sigma^{k-n} E.$$